# AFNetworking GET json values and save it NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm new to ios and its developing. i have clean code with set Correctly `AFNetworking`.My base URl's json Encording has got JSON objects and arrays as well as values . in my JSON out put i want to get values of "thumbnail" every time i do im getting Null .please help me to get "name ,thumbnail,id,images " of my json output. please find my NSDictionary type printed object's NSlog.

```
2014-07-20 09:08:33.110 WADTourisum[1157:60b] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2014-07-20 09:08:33.879 WADTourisum[1157:60b] JSON: {
    Main =     (
                {
            id = 1;
            "image_bundle_id" = 1;
            images =             (
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/oceans/slide_images/1.jpg",
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/oceans/slide_images/2.jpg",
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/oceans/slide_images/3.jpg"
            );
            name = OCEAN;
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/ocean.jpg";
        },
                {
            id = 2;
            "image_bundle_id" = 23;
            images =             (
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/heritages/slide_images/1.jpg",
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/heritages/slide_images/2.jpg",
                "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/heritages/slide_images/3.png"
            );
            name = Heritage;
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/heritage.jpg";
        },
                {
            id = 3;
            "image_bundle_id" = 0;
            images =             (
            );
            name = "Tea Country";
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/teaCountry.jpg";
        },
                {
            id = 4;
            "image_bundle_id" = 0;
            images =             (
            );
            name = "WILD LIFE";
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/wildLife.jpg";
        },
                {
            id = 5;
            "image_bundle_id" = 0;
            images =             (
            );
            name = Culture;
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/culture.jpg";
        },
                {
            id = 6;
            "image_bundle_id" = 0;
            images =             (
            );
            name = "NIGHT LIFE";
            thumbnail = "http://wearedesigners.net/clients/clients12/tourism/images/guides/thumbs/nightLife.jpg";
        }
    );
```

}

my code snippit

```
-(void) retriveData
{



    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager GET:@"http://www.fr20.wearedesigners.net/WADMac/tourism/fetchGuideListAndroid.php"
     parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         self.posts =(NSDictionary *)responseObject;
         self.post =self.posts[@"thumbnail"];




        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", self.post);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please log into internetet"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];







}
```

Comment: Can you also include the code which results to the following: `get values of "thumbnail" every time i do im getting Null `

Comment: @dezinezync 2014-07-20 18:56:08.062 WADTourisum[1551:60b] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2014-07-20 18:56:08.848 WADTourisum[1551:60b] JSON: (null)

Comment: I'm guessing the prop `post` is a `NSArray`?

Comment: @yes dude its @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray * post;

Comment: @dezinezync please find my edited code all i want is getting JSON values of thumbnail

Comment: your updated code is not going to work. Do you want an NSArray of all the thumbnail URLs only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the response and the only problem i see is you are not able to retrieve values correctly.

While fetching data from JSON remember that in which format you are getting the data i.e. either you are getting arrays or dictionary.

Seeing your response you are getting Array which in itself contains dictionary.

use the below code to fetch the values

```
NSArray *array = [responseObject valueForKey:@"Main"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        NSInteger ids = [[dict valueForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *thumbnail = [dict valueForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSArray *arrImages = [dict valueForKey:@"images"];
        //You can use them accordingly

    }
```

Hope this helps you. Happy coding :)

Comment: yap it works for me thank you very much can you please tell me the get index of particular value please i mean id=3 has this thumbnail like that please :)

Comment: @RehanK can you elaborate it a bit

Comment: i want to make a class with two properties for thubanali and name. and i want to keep that class reference with index (java call object array) how do i do it here thank you for your advance so far :)

Comment: can you elaborate this in detail or you can post another question in detail regarding this problem